# Delete duplicated values from Map/HashMap and get the most frequent value

Tags: java, hashmap, memory-efficient

I have tried to delete map entries but haven't figured out how yet, mean awhile I made another map.

1. I need to find occurrences in several sentences. (I don't know the
   sentences neither the words that may appear in them).
2. Get the most concurrent word in the sentence, no matter upper or lower case and accents.
3. Get the second and third concurrent word in the sentence.
4. Print the top concurrent words with their number of appearances.
5. **Be as efficient as it could be.**

Point 5 is the most important, following you will see what I have so far.

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String stringTest = "En esta cadena tenemos mas cadenas que la cadena principal la primera vez que intente esta solucion no pude mas que intentar una y otra vez vez vez vez";
        new StringTest(stringTest);

    }

    public StringTest(String string) {

        String [] splitString = string.split(" ");
        Map<String, Integer> mapString = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        mapString.put(splitString[0], 1);

        for (int i=1; i <= splitString.length-1; i++){
            if (mapString.containsKey(splitString[i])){
                mapString.put(splitString[i], mapString.get(splitString[i])+1);
            } else{
                mapString.put(splitString[i], 1);
            }
        }

        Map<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapString.entrySet()){
            if (entry.getValue()!=1){
                newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(newMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple of things: 1. Why put the first element in the map? I wouldn't do "mapString.put(splitString[0], 1);" but change your loop to start at 0; 2. You need a variable to hold a trim() value. you are checking for trim(), but putting it in the map untrimmed. A simple "String key = splitString[I].trim();" would work. then work with key.

Comment: also item 4: "print the top concurrent words with their number of appearances" to read they want the highest occurrences first. May-be I'm wrong, but if it's correct, you may need to sort the output.

Comment: @Dakoda 1.- I tried to skip an IF doing "mapString.put(splitString[0], 1);" also tried to skip one iteration of the loop. 2.- I left old code, trim shouldn't be needed because I made an split on the original sentence. About your second comment I can sort the output however I don't need to keep in the map all the Keys-Values I just need to maintain the top 3 occurrences.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't think of you splitting on spaces. You're right. My second comment was only a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello here is my solution using your example

```
public class StringTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringTest = "En esta cadena tenemos mas cadenas que la cadena principal la primera vez que intente esta solucion no pude mas que intentar una y otra vez vez vez vez";
    new StringTest(stringTest);

}

public StringTest(String string) {

    String[] splitString = string.split(" ");

    Map<String, Integer> mapString = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // Loop the array
    for (String token : splitString) {
        // Convert token to lowerCase
        token = token.toLowerCase();
        if (mapString.containsKey(token)) {
            mapString.put(token, mapString.get(token) + 1);
        } else {
            mapString.put(token, 1);
        }
    }

    // Convert Map to List of Map
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(mapString.entrySet());

    // Sort list with Collections.sort(), provide a custom Comparator
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            // o2 first that the order was descendant
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });

    System.out.println("The most concurrent Word: " + list.get(0).getKey());
    System.out.println("The second word is: " + list.get(1).getKey() + ", an third is: " + list.get(2).getKey());
    System.out.println("The top concurrent words are");

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
        if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
            System.out.println(entry);

        }
    }
}
```

}